# Engine can't keep idle after reving it too much

Tags: engine, idle, ktm

I have a motorcycle, ktm, and when I start it, no gear, if accelerate it over 10k rpm, when it tries to go back to idle, the engine stops, because the rpm go way too low.

What can it be ? Inyector ? spark plug?

Comment: Does it have an idle control valve?

Comment: It does, and its set to preserve the idle recommended by the owners manual. The problem happens only when there is no gear.

Comment: Is the idle control valve electronically controlled?  If so, check that it is not dirty which may stop it opening correctly when requested.  In gear, the momentum of the bike is probably keeping the engine turning while the ECU tries to compensate for the lack of air flow.

Comment: This is not an answer for sure, but I have to ask the question.  Why are you running the engine at 10k rpm in neutral?   KTM’s are great bikes, and I agree that it shouldn’t stall, but why put a strain like that on the bike?

Comment: I just bought the motorcycle (im the 3rd owner) and a friend of mine wanted to rev it in order to hear how it sounds. I don't do it on a regular basis, but I didn't like the result.